# Way to send report with sp_send_dbmail that only has records available

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This SP is called on by sp_send_dbmail, which is executed daily on a job. When this does not have any records to show on report, I do not want the section sent with '0 rows affected' I still want to report the sections that have records available.

here is my sp it actually has 15 separate select statements, but for the sake of saving space I am only showing 2

```
------------------------------------------THIS IS FOR DEPARTMENT CODE [FS - FD]
DECLARE 
@Now2 DATETIME,
@EndReportDate2 DATETIME,
@StartReportDate2 DATETIME
SET @Now2 = GETDATE()
SET @EndReportDate2 = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now2), -1)
SET @StartReportDate2 = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now2), -1)
SELECT StatDate = TimeLog.EventDate 
,[ID#] = a.ID
,Codes = (a.DeptCode + '-' +  a.OpCode)
,TotalTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0))  
,Units = SUM(Units)
,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
,[Goal%] = (convert(varchar,cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/1552*100 as decimal(10,0))) + '%')
,AssociateName = (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName)
FROM PTW.dbo.TimeLog a LEFT JOIN PTW.dbo.AssociateInfo b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @StartReportDate2  AND @EndReportDate2  AND DeptCode = 'FS' AND OpCode = 'FD'
GROUP BY a.EventDate, a.ID, a.DeptCode, a.OpCode, b.FirstName, b.LastName
ORDER BY   UPH DESC
------------------------------------------THIS IS FOR DEPARTMENT CODE [FS - FT]
DECLARE 
@Now3 DATETIME,
@EndReportDate3 DATETIME,
@StartReportDate3 DATETIME
SET @Now3 = GETDATE()
SET @EndReportDate3 = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now3), -1)
SET @StartReportDate3 = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @Now3), -1)
SELECT StatDate = a.EventDate 
,[ID#] = a.ID
,Codes = (a.DeptCode + '-' +  a.OpCode)
,TotalTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0))  
,Units = SUM(Units)
,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
,[Goal%] = (convert(varchar,cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/295*100 as decimal(10,0))) + '%')
,AssociateName = (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName)
FROM PTW.dbo.TimeLog a LEFT JOIN PTW.dbo.AssociateInfo b 
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @StartReportDate3  AND @EndReportDate3  AND DeptCode = 'FS' AND OpCode = 'FT'
GROUP BY a.EventDate, a.ID, a.DeptCode, a.OpCode, b.FirstName, b.LastName
ORDER BY  UPH DESC
```

Here where I call for it with sp_send_dbmail

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'DBMail,
@recipients = 'me@me.com',
@subject = 'FLAT_Daily',
@query = N'EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily',
@query_attachment_filename = 'FLAT_Daily.txt'
```

Here are my results

```
StatDate    ID#       Codes TotalTime   Units   UPH   Goal%  AssociateName
--------    ---       ----- ---------   -----   ---   -----  -------------
7/24/2017   1234567   FS-FD 03:40:00    0       0     0%     MY NAME

(1 rows affected)
StatDate    ID#       Codes TotalTime   Units   UPH  Goal%   AssociateName
--------    ---       ----- ---------   -----   ---  -----   -------------

(0 rows affected)
```

Some days I have records on both, but like the example sometimes only one portion has records. How can I send only what has records available?

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Would also like to group resultset like below. Showing only same `associateName` with all department `codes` individual worked in for the specified time.

```
StatDate   ID          Codes TotalTime Units       UPH     Goal   AssociateName
---------- ----------- ----- --------- ----------- ------- ------ ------------------
2017-07-26 2375935     fs-ft 03:44:00  263         70      24%    Druid Druid
2017-07-26 2375935     fs-fd 04:50:00  553         114     7%     Druid Druid
2017-07-26 2375935     fr-pk 04:50:00  553         114     7%     Druid Druid

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to move the reusable query into its own procedure, and execute that procedure from your daily report procedure.

This still just uses `if exists()` to determine whether or not to return a result set as suggested by Nick McDermaid, but it simplifies the code.

```
create procedure dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily_Query (
    @StartReportDate datetime 
  , @EndReportDate   datetime 
  , @DeptCode        char(2) 
  , @OpCode          char(2)
  , @Goal            decimal(10,2)
) as 
begin;
  --set nocount on; /* removes (N row(s) affected message)
  if exists (
    select 1 
    from TimeLog t
    where t.EventDate >= @StartReportDate
      and t.EventDate <= @EndReportDate
      and t.DeptCode = @DeptCode
      and t.OpCode = @OpCode
    )
  begin;
    select 
        StatDate = convert(char(10),t.EventDate,120)
      , t.ID
      , Codes = (t.DeptCode + '-' +  t.OpCode)
      , TotalTime = right('0' + convert(varchar(9),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 3600 )),2) + ':' 
                  + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) / 60) % 60 ),2) + ':' 
                  + right('0' + convert(varchar(2),(sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)) % 60 )),2)
      , Units = sum(Units)
      , UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
      , [Goal%] = (convert(varchar(30),cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/nullif(@Goal,0)*100 as decimal(10,0))) + '%')
      , AssociateName = isnull(ai.FirstName + ' ','') + isnull(ai.LastName,'')
    from TimeLog t
      left join AssociateInfo ai
        on t.Id = ai.Id
    where t.EventDate >= @StartReportDate
      and t.EventDate <= @EndReportDate
      and t.DeptCode = @DeptCode
      and t.OpCode = @OpCode
    group by t.EventDate, t.id, t.DeptCode, t.OpCode, ai.FirstName, ai.LastName
    order by t.id desc;
  end;
end;
go
```

Then in your daily procedure, reuse your variables and execute the procedure for the query with each set of variables needed.

The code in the example below is verbose and repeats the same value assignments for the same variables, but I left it this way to make it easy to adjust for your actual code.

```
create procedure dbo.SP_Flat_Daily as 
begin;
  --set nocount on; /* removes (N row(s) affected message)
  declare 
      @Now             datetime
    , @StartReportDate datetime 
    , @EndReportDate   datetime 
    , @DeptCode        char(2) 
    , @OpCode          char(2)
    , @Goal            decimal(10,2);
  ------------------------------------------THIS IS FOR DEPARTMENT CODE [FS - FT]
  select 
      @Now = getdate()
    , @StartReportDate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
    , @EndReportDate   = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
    , @DeptCode = 'fs'
    , @OpCode   = 'ft'
    , @Goal     = 295.0;
  exec dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily_Query @StartReportDate, @EndReportDate, @DeptCode, @OpCode, @Goal;  
  ------------------------------------------THIS IS FOR DEPARTMENT CODE [NA - NA]
  select 
      @Now = getdate()
    , @StartReportDate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
    , @EndReportDate   = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
    , @DeptCode = 'na'
    , @OpCode   = 'na'
    , @Goal     = 0;
  exec dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily_Query @StartReportDate, @EndReportDate, @DeptCode, @OpCode, @Goal;
  ------------------------------------------THIS IS FOR DEPARTMENT CODE [FS - FD]
  select 
      @Now = getdate()
    , @StartReportDate = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
    , @EndReportDate   = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -1)
    , @DeptCode = 'fs'
    , @OpCode   = 'fd'
    , @Goal     = 1552.0;
  exec dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily_Query @StartReportDate, @EndReportDate, @DeptCode, @OpCode, @Goal;
end;
go
exec dbo.SP_Flat_Daily;
```

dbfiddle.uk demo: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=72525c7478361b0df8171fd224f68f7e

returns:

```
StatDate   ID          Codes TotalTime Units       UPH     Goal   AssociateName
---------- ----------- ----- --------- ----------- ------- ------ ------------------
2017-07-26 2375935     fs-ft 03:44:00  263         70      24%    Druid Druid

(1 row(s) affected)

StatDate   ID          Codes TotalTime Units       UPH     Goal   AssociateName
---------- ----------- ----- --------- ----------- ------- ------ ------------------
2017-07-26 11259       fs-fd 04:50:00  553         114     7%     Sql Zim
2017-07-26 25          fs-fd 24:59:59  176         7       0%     Nick McDermaid

(2 row(s) affected)
```

As you can see, there is no message or empty result set for `na-na`.

Comment: This executes beautifully, thanks Sql Zim. Only thing is I use `[Goal%]= (convert(varchar,cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/1552*100 as decimal(10,0))) + '%')` for each different `DeptCode` and `OpCode`. The `SP_FLAT_Daily_Query` does not show the `[Goal%]` I would put in there but each `OpCode` has a different standard I set. I failed to show this on the initial question, sorry,. I just updated OQ

Comment: @DRUIDRUID Since the formula appears to be the same except for the `295` vs `1552` you could just use another variable and pass it to the procedure like so: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=72525c7478361b0df8171fd224f68f7e

Comment: This works great. If I do not have a `Goal%` to divide by I simply remove the `@Goal` from each select statement. This will return a `NULL` value in the column. I am happy with result and your script and help. Thanks SqlZim

Comment: Hey @SqlZim . I have a question. If the ` , @Goal     = 0;` and we have a value of `0` for `Units` then we will get an error.

Comment: @DRUIDRUID Just wrap `@Goal` with `nullif()` like so: `nullif(@Goal,0)`

Comment: Adding it here to `dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily_Query` like this correct? `, [Goal%] = (convert(varchar(30),cast((isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60)/nullif(@Goal,0)*100 as decimal(10,0))) + '%')`

Comment: Lets say I wanted to have each result set show stats for each `AssociateName` There will be multiple rows of the same `AssociateName` with all the `DeptCode` and `OpCode` in the resultset? See the requested results at bottom of original question. You da man!

Comment: @DRUIDRUID You could do something like this: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=3d32477e9eaf4331d44e15d192243a1a  but that would use the same `@goal` for each code set, if you want different goals for each code set you'd need to use a table, temp table, or table variable with it.

Comment: Thanks but I tried something similar earlier and that will not work for what we need here... That's where I'm stuck at, what you referred to is beyond my SQL savvy. We would need the different goals for each code

Comment: hey there. Would you be able to help with another question I posted? Calculate time elapsed from one column https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204427/calculate-elapsed-time-from-one-column?noredirect=1#comment85414680_49204427

Answer (score 1):

Begin each select in `IF EXISTS`. For example:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM PTW.dbo.TimeLog
    WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @StartReportDate2  AND @EndReportDate2  
    AND DeptCode = 'FS' AND OpCode = 'FD'
    )

SELECT StatDate = TimeLog.EventDate 
,[ID#] = a.ID
,Codes = (a.DeptCode + '-' +  a.OpCode)
,TotalTime = convert(time(0),dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,StartTime,FinishTime)),0))  
,Units = SUM(Units)
,UPH = cast(isnull(sum(Units) / nullif(sum(datediff(minute,StartTime,FinishTime))*1.0,0),0.0)*60  as decimal(10,0))
,AssociateName = (b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName)
FROM PTW.dbo.TimeLog a LEFT JOIN PTW.dbo.AssociateInfo b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @StartReportDate2  AND @EndReportDate2  AND DeptCode = 'FS' AND OpCode = 'FD'
GROUP BY a.EventDate, a.ID, a.DeptCode, a.OpCode, b.FirstName, b.LastName
ORDER BY   UPH DESC

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM query2)
SELECT column from query2
```

If records exist, the next line will be executed

Comment: I tried this, if the first select statement does not have any records to populate the query will not move past to execute the 2nd select statement. And if the fist has records and the second does not, I will still see the `0 rows effected` for that area on the report

Comment: Is that what you see when you run `EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily` directly? That's not how `if` works, unless you use `begin` and `end`. There's no `begin` and `end` in my sample, meaning that each `if` only affects the next statement

Comment: just tried a few options with `begin` and `end`, still seeing same, showing `0 rows effected`

Comment: Are you testing `EXEC PTW.dbo.SP_FLAT_Daily` directly or not? I just tested the exists approach as described in my answer (note: no BEGIN/END) and it definitely works that way. Maybe the email component is messing it up. I probably can't help any further